# How to pack 3D boxes into a bigger box?

Tags: packing-and-covering

Given a box of given size $L\times M\times N$ and a list of smaller boxes of given sizes $(l_i,m_i,n_i)$, decide whether the smaller boxes altogether fit into the big box (and produce such a packing if possible).

The problem is NP-complete...so I am looking for a good heuristic algorithm...the algorithm should allow for (the obvious possible) rotations of the boxes.

What are currently good/best heuristic algorithms and codes? Links to papers or webpages are also welcome.

Comment: dynamic programming might work well on instances which are not too big, IMHO

Comment: Which rotations are the obvious ones? All of them? Or only those $4$ leaving the base on the bottom, as you would pack actual boxes?

Comment: @ZackWolske: In the paper I cited below, they consider all $90^\circ$ rotations: "We consider orthogonal packings where ninety-degree rotations are allowed."

Comment: With "obvious" rotations I meant those that keep edges parallel to coordinate axes...in other words: multiples of 90 degrees.

Answer (score 8):

Here are two sources, the first of which is the
more substantive. The problem is even hard to approximate,
but algorithms are available that achieve about $2\frac{1}{2} \times$ the optimal packing.

> (1) Miyazawa, Flavio Keidi, and Yoshiko Wakabayashi. "Three-dimensional packings with rotations." *Computers & Operations Research*. 36.10 (2009): 2801-2815.
>   ([PDF download](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~fkm/publication/rotation.pdf).)

---

[image: BinPacking1]

---

> (2) E. Dube, L.R. Kanavathy. "Optimizing three-dimensional bin packing through simulation." *Proc. Modeling, Simulation, Optimization*. 2006. 
>   ([PDF download](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bb99/86af2f26f7726fcef1bc684eac8239c9b853.pdf?_ga=1.50320358.1394974689.1485463187)

---

[image: BinPacking2]

---

Comment: Looking either figure, it's easy to imagine a long, narrow box lying diagonally on the top.

Comment: @SteveHuntsman: Yes, both algorithms only pack "orthogonally," but permitting all $90^\circ$ rotations.

Comment: @SteveHuntsman: See my comment above. Rotations should leave edges of boxes parallel to coordinate axes.

Comment: @RaymondHemmecke: That is the assumption in both papers I cited.

Comment: Yes. But as Steve talked about "boxes lying diagonally" and as there was a question on what I meant with "obvious rotations", I clarified it here, too.

Answer (score 5):

It would probably take some work to turn this into an algorithm that can deal with rotations of the boxes, but you might be able to modify [the three weight algorithm](http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.1961) (a variation of ADMM) by Derbinsky, Bento, Elser, and Yedidia, which is a fairly simple algorithm that has recently beaten various records for circle and sphere packing in boxes.